# Tooltip doesn't show outside an (overflow-y: auto) container

Tags: html, css

I have a container box with large data, and need the overflow-y to be auto on this container to scroll since the height is limited on the page.
Inside this container, some elements have tooltips. The tooltips of course show on hover and have to be `position: absolute`.
My problem is that the tooltips don't show outside the parent container since `overflow-y: auto`.

Is there a workaround for this problem? I failed to find other questions that address this problem.

Code:

```css
.box {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-text {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-text">I am an idiot, and this is a long text to demonstrate it.</div>
    <p class="text">Hover here!</p>
  </div>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
  <p class="text">Some data here.</p>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tfbh5aj/9/

Comment: remove overflow:hidden

Comment: The `overflow: hidden` is needed. Can't remove it. This is just an example, but I have specific needs that require this property to be present.

Comment: *but I have specific needs that require this property to be present.* --> share it, don't give us a generic example that is far from your specific needs

Comment: Put `div.tooltip-text` outside of `div.box`, not children of `div.box`

Comment: As you didn't clarify your 'specif needs' i can't give you a good answer, but i can suggest to extract the tool-tip  and move it outside the div with "box" class, and maybe put both of them inside another div to have a better control over positioning, check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/HosseinKD/ag514juo/11/
"note the usage of "+" selector in css section"

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for the feedback. I updated the question with more relevant information as much as possible. @HosseinKaramzadeh's answer is interesting since I did not know about the `+` selector in CSS, though it doesn't solve the problem completely since the placement of the tooltip needs to be close to the hovered text.

Answer (score 0):

make a container and put `.box` and `.tooltip` in it as sibling children:

```
.container -   
         .box    
         .tooltip
```

If a parent is overflow hidden, no way, children are hidden outside of view. So better to separate them and relate them to one main container

```css
main {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
      }
      section {
        background: #e9e9e9;
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        overflow: scroll;
      }
      div {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: -10%;
        left: 50%;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        min-width: 100%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: black;
        color: white;
      }
      section:hover ~ div,
      div:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
```

```html
<main>
      <section>
        <p>Hover here</p>
      </section>
      <div>
        <p>this is a long text to demonstrate it</p>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly serve my purpose of showing the tooltip right above or below the desired element. It would need manual placement.